# Spawning a task in tokio from tokio::test

Tags: rust, async-await, rust-tokio

I have roughly the following `tokio::main`:

```rust
#[tokio::main]
pub async fn my_tokio_main() {
    let addr = "[::1]:9002";
    let listener = TcpListener::bind(&addr).await.expect("Can't listen");

    while let Ok((stream, _)) = listener.accept().await {
        // Handle the connection
    }
}
```

With roughly the following test:

```rust
#[tokio::test]
async fn test_hello() {
    task::spawn(my_tokio_main());
//              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `()` is not a future

}
```

However, when building the test, the compiler complains that *`()` is not a future*.

My understanding is that because `my_tokio_main()` is `async`, then it *does* return a future. Why is the compiler complaining here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the `#[tokio::main]` attribute on the `main` function. This attribute will transform the function into a synchronous function, which creates a tokio runtime and will call `runtime.block_on(future)`  where `future` is the result of the defined async function.

Therefore the actually generated `my_tokio_main` is synchronous. You could seperate the `tokio::main` wrapper and the `async` function definition in order to call into the async function from another async function.